# Run bat cmd in every sub-folder fail

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, cmd

I need to run a bat file to rename the photo in each sub-folder as the sub-folder name and copy all the photos to a new folder. Each sub-folder contains only one photo.

I would like to write a batch file to do this task as there are many sub-folders, however, I can only successfully copy the photo in the last sub-folder.

The sub-folders are naming by number sequence starting from "00000001".

I found that the photos are renamed as the same thus only one photo can be copied.

Here's my code:

```
md "D:\photo"

for /r %%d in (.) do (cd %%d
for /r %%* in (.) do (set CurrDirName=%%~n*
echo %CurrDirName%
ren "*.jpg" "%CurrDirName%.jpg"
copy *.jpg "D:\photo"))
```

Please advice so that I could modify my code and do what I would like to do successfully, thanks a lot!

**EDIT with more details**

In cmd line, for example the program are running in the sub-foler "00000127"
set CurrDirName=00000127
but echo the %CurrDirName%, shows 00000128 which is the last sub-folder and every sub-folder return 00000128 but not the CurrDirName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this & remove the `echo` if the output is ok.

```
@echo off &setlocal
set "destination=d:\photo"
md "%destination%" 2>nul
for /d /r %%d in (*.*) do (
    pushd  "%%d"
    for %%i in (*.*) do echo copy "%%~i" "%destination%\%%~nd.jpg"
    popd
)
endlocal
```

There must be **only one photo** in each subfolder!